# how to set email format for textbox in adobe Acrobat

Tags: adobe, acrobat

I don't understand about javascript.
how do i set my textbox into email format ?
what i found is [validating](https://acrobatusers.com/forum/forms-acrobat/creating-email-address-format-text-box-formatting/) the textbox instead.

when i try to follow this [example](https://answers.acrobatusers.com/Formatting-a-custom-phone-number-in-Text-Field-Properties-Format-q113307.aspx) by setting format arbitary. by putting it this regex `/^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9.-]{2,4}$/` nothing happen. Hence is it possible to set a mask on textbox (acrobat) ?

if in `winforms` you can easily set a mask on the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Text Field with an e-mail Address Field Validation or an e-mail Field Type.

**Set the validation for a field**: double-click the field and choosing an option from the Validation list

Comment: i don't quite get it. there's no e-mail Field Validation or e-mail Field Type. in visual studio you can mask it, e.g when the user type 1 character like 'a' it automatically pops `a_____@____` on the textbox. how to do that ?. on Above it only causes validation when user change focus and said error if not meets existing regex